# Process Dimensions & Facts separately, to have same effect as processing the entire cube

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, olap-cube

I have about `4 fact` tables and about `19 dimensions` for a `SSAS cube`.
Initially, my job to process the `cube`, processed the entire cube in a single process/xmla. Now, I had to conditionally process some `facts`, so I removed the processing of the entire `cube` and decided to separately process all the facts and dimensions(in the dtsx package of course).
The logic for which looks like..

```
if ( some condition ) then do ProcessFull for the fact1 table
else do ProcessDefault for the fact1 table
```

I used a `Precedence Constraint` for the if `expression`.
And similarly for the remaining `facts`. And finally for all the `dimensions`.

Now my question is, would processing all the `facts` and all the `dimensions` thus, is equivalent to processing the entire `cube` ?

What I observe is that, my job to process separately runs and processes all the `facts` and `dimensions`, but i am not able to browse the `cube`. It gives the error:

```
The cube cannot be browsed. Verify that the cube has been deployed and processed.
```

I am pretty new to SSAS, so may be I am missing out on something, please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

what sequence you used for processing facts and dim? and what processing type you used for dimension processing? If you are doing process full or process data for dim then it will make other objects unprocessed.
Can refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms174774.aspx if this is of any help

Comment: I'm processing the facts and dimensions in parallel. For all the dimensions the processing type is Process Full. The processing of facts is conditional. Some will be default type and others full process type.

Comment: Process full for dimension is making your cube unprocessed. You can test this on your local setup. Pick any dim and process it with process full and then try to browse . It wont allow you . If your dim tables will have data addition only then you can go for process update. That wont affect the other objects.

Comment: Would it matter if I process all the dimensions first and then process all the facts?

Comment: If you process full any dim , I think you have to process the cube else it wont be available for browsing.

Comment: I changed the processing of dimensions to default and it worked, Would it make any difference up on deletion of data from the data ware house and using this Type of operation for processing the Dimensions?

Actually, I want to achieve the same result as Full processing a cube, by processing the dimensions and facts separately..